# How to toggle play and pause a track by SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I am trying to make a button to toggle play and pause a song. I used `sound.play()` and `sound.pause()` methods but only `play()` works and it never stops.

Here is how I tried to make it working:

```
    function player(){
    var sound = SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
        if(is_playing==="true") { 
            sound.pause(); 
            is_playing = "false";
        } 
        else if (is_playing === "false") { 
            sound.play(); 
            is_playing = "true";
        }
    });
    }
```

Here is the demo: [jsfiddle.net/wZZ4D/](http://jsfiddle.net/wZZ4D/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should instantiate, `play` and also `pause` if there's anything playing:

```
var is_playing = false,
    sound;
function player(){
    if( sound ) {
        if(is_playing) {
            sound.pause();
            is_playing = false;
        } else {
            sound.play();
            is_playing = true;
        }
    } else {
        SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(obj){
            obj.play();
            sound = obj;
            is_playing = true;
        });
    }
}
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/wZZ4D/1/)

I was wondering if there's a `resume` method; it could also be incorporated into the code. I did a quick test, and indeed there's a `resume` method to continue playing from where it was paused at.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works the way I wanted. There is also a Toggle method but somehow it does not work. anyway thanks